# how to set property in .properties file before spring come into picture?

Tags: spring

I have password coming from command line argument now before initializing/instantiating any bean in IOC container I want to set the password to one key in .properties file. So spring will get the same property from that .properties file to instantiate datasource object. How can I do that? please help.

Comment: Why store it in a properties file? Just add it to the system properties and spring will still be able to resolve it.

Comment: but the thing is all properties require to instantiate datasource, we are putting in .properties file. only for password encryption we want to pass it from command line.

Comment: That doesn't matter, spring can consult system properties, environment properties, property files, jndi properties to resolve placeholders. So where they come from doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

project.properties

```
# DB Info
jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:db/myapp
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.password=
jdbc.maxConnections=25
```

spring beans.xml

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:project.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driver}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${jdbc.user}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: but where actually we are assigning password ?

Comment: <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>